# Can anyone explain this C password hashing algorithm?

Tags: c, hash, password-encryption

I am trying to replicate the below code in php to have a web based account creation script but I do not really understand what is happening before the md5 hash.

This is the code:

```
reg_seconds = (unsigned) regtime / 3600L;
ch = strlen (&password[0]);
_itoa (reg_seconds, &config_data[0], 10 );
//Throw some salt in the game ;)
sprintf (&password[ch], "_%s_salt", &config_data[0] );
//printf ("New password = %s\n", password );
MDString (&password[0], &MDBuffer[0] );
for (ch=0;ch<16;ch++)
    sprintf (&md5password[ch*2], "%02x", (unsigned char) MDBuffer[ch]);
md5password[32] = 0;
```

When using the password "password" and a regtime of "399969" I get a hashed password of "9a5c041c5b37febc90ad3dc66ec62c83"

Could anyone explain what exactly is happening and what the final string is that gets hashed?

Comment: What step do you have problem understanding?

Comment: `ch = strlen(&password[0]);` - why?

Comment: This is an excellent example of how we should **not** hash passwords. I know this is not your code, but be aware that those passwords are not protected only obfuscated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's look line by line, assuming password = "password" and regtime = 399969

```
reg_seconds = (unsigned) regtime / 3600L;
=> reg_seconds = 111    NB incoherent with the name, isn't is regtime % 3600L
ch = strlen (&password[0]);
=> ch = 8
_itoa (reg_seconds, &config_data[0], 10 );
=> config_data = "111"
//Throw some salt in the game ;)
sprintf (&password[ch], "_%s_salt", &config_data[0] );
=> password = "password_111_salt"
//printf ("New password = %s\n", password );  Why did not you uncomment this ?
MDString (&password[0], &MDBuffer[0] );
MDBuffer receives the binary hash
for (ch=0;ch<16;ch++)
    sprintf (&md5password[ch*2], "%02x", (unsigned char) MDBuffer[ch]);
md5password[32] = 0;
md5password receives the hex encoded hash : "033f7d591eda915e708571edd255b511"
```

Oups it is not the expected hash !

Because 399969 is **not** regtime but is reg_seconds in above code... So

```
password = "password_399969_salt"
md5password = "9a5c041c5b37febc90ad3dc66ec62c83"
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!! This is not my code, I'm just trying to understand it. Seeing the final string makes it really easy to understand :)